# How to extend an interface with an async function?

Tags: typescript

What might be a good way to go about extending an interface with an `async function` in TypeScript?

It might be useful to add a property to the `async function`, serving as something resembling a constant, [as in this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Augmentation%20%3D%20'Augmentation'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20OriginalExample%20%3D%20typeof%20example%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AugmentedExample%20extends%20OriginalExample%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AUGMENTATION%3A%20Augmentation%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20AUGMENTATION%20%3D%20'Augmentation'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20example(a%3A%20number)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09return%20true%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20augmentedExecutor%20%3D%20example%20as%20any%20as%20AugmentedExample%3B%0D%0AaugmentedExecutor.AUGMENTATION%20%3D%20AUGMENTATION%3B).

However, I haven't been able to extend this approach in such a manner that the `AugmentedExample` interface can be applied to multiple different `async function`s.

[In this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Augmentation%20%3D%20'Augmentation'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20OriginalExample%20%3D%20typeof%20example%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AugmentedExample%20%3CGenericOriginalExample%3E%20extends%20GenericOriginalExample%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AUGMENTATION%3A%20Augmentation%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20AUGMENTATION%20%3D%20'Augmentation'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20example(a%3A%20number)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09return%20true%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20augmentedExecutor%20%3D%20example%20as%20any%20as%20AugmentedExample%20%3Ctypeof%20example%3E%3B%0D%0AaugmentedExecutor.AUGMENTATION%20%3D%20AUGMENTATION%3B), a generic is supplied to the interface, but TypeScript throws an exception: `An interface may only extend a class or another interface.` This is understandable, because TypeScript cannot be certain that the generic is something which can be used to extend an interface. However, I haven't been able to work out a way to constrain the generic such that TypeScript can be certain that it can be used to extend an interface.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe function composition can be a way, I have not experiment with it in TypeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an intersection type instead of interface extension:

```
type Augmentation = 'Augmentation';

type AugmentedExample <GenericOriginalExample> = GenericOriginalExample &
{
    AUGMENTATION: Augmentation;
};

const AUGMENTATION = 'Augmentation';

async function example(a: number)
{
    return true;
};

const augmentedExecutor = example as AugmentedExample <typeof example>;
augmentedExecutor.AUGMENTATION = AUGMENTATION;
```